# Using sidekiq-unique-jobs gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I'm trying to use the sidekiq-unique-jobs but honestly can't get it to do anything it's supposed to do.
I'm trying to not be able to queue the same job multiple times (while it's already in the queue or running), but as you see here, I kick off a worker with the same ID 3 times and it runs each time.

Rails 5.2.1
Sidekiq 6.0.6

Any ideas?

Here's the worker:

```
class RefreshLoginWorker

  include Sidekiq::Worker
  include Sidekiq::Status::Worker

  sidekiq_options queue: 'credentials', :retry => false, lock: :until_executed

  def perform item_id
    sleep 5
  end

end
```

Here we kick off some job one after another:

```
irb(main):016:0> RefreshLoginWorker.perform_async 20
=> "4e83f7a419b9aa047860af77"
irb(main):017:0> RefreshLoginWorker.perform_async 20
=> "682776c2fb45866f35cbf87f"
irb(main):018:0> RefreshLoginWorker.perform_async 20
=> "962dc0bae18cfc4ede6aea18"
```

Sidekiq log:

```
2020-07-18T17:30:48.468Z pid=561643 tid=gpbejyaar class=RefreshLoginWorker jid=4e83f7a419b9aa047860af77 INFO: start
2020-07-18T17:30:49.060Z pid=561643 tid=gpbejy9vf class=RefreshLoginWorker jid=682776c2fb45866f35cbf87f INFO: start
2020-07-18T17:30:53.469Z pid=561643 tid=gpbejyaar class=RefreshLoginWorker jid=4e83f7a419b9aa047860af77 elapsed=5.001 INFO: done
2020-07-18T17:30:53.470Z pid=561643 tid=gpbejyaar class=RefreshLoginWorker jid=962dc0bae18cfc4ede6aea18 INFO: start
2020-07-18T17:30:54.061Z pid=561643 tid=gpbejy9vf class=RefreshLoginWorker jid=682776c2fb45866f35cbf87f elapsed=5.001 INFO: done
2020-07-18T17:30:58.471Z pid=561643 tid=gpbejyaar class=RefreshLoginWorker jid=962dc0bae18cfc4ede6aea18 elapsed=5.001 INFO: done
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you say Rails 2.5.1; I assume that's a typo?

Comment: Hah, yes, updated

Comment: Does `SidekiqUniqueJobs.config.enabled` give you `true`? Have you tried setting the `on_conflict` setting to get better insides into whether or not the gem actually considers something to be a conflict?

Comment: FWIW, with a fresh 5.2.1 project and 6.1.1 Sidekiq, your job works as I'd expect. With the ``on_conflict: :log`` option set, I get a ``INFO: skipping job with id (...)`` and a ``nil`` return. The only way I can reproduce your results is setting ``SidekiqUniqueJobs.config.enabled`` to ``false``, so I'd echo @ClemensKofler's suggestion to check that.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly use `gem 'sidekiq-unique-jobs'` and then `bundle`. After installation you should enable sidekiq-unique-jobs with `SidekiqUniqueJobs.config.enabled`. For more details follow [sidekiq-unique-jobs](https://github.com/mhenrixon/sidekiq-unique-jobs)